# How to write a new dataset with the frequencies until x row in curent dataset?

Tags: r

So I have this dataset which looks like this:

```
Day     A   B   C   D
01.01   6   3   4   9
01.02   3   7   3   2
01.03   2   10  9   2
01.04   1   1   5   9
01.05   1   1   1   10
01.06   1   9   5   5
01.07   4   3   7   7
01.08   7   7   9   4
01.09   9   9   8   4
01.10   5   7   3   1
```

A,B,C and D are stores, and 1 to 10 are the items that had the biggest number of sellings in that day in that store. So in the A store they could've sold a number of any of the items, but the item no. 6 was the best selling item in day 1.
So far my nominal frequency table for all the stores looks like this:

```
Item    count of item
1           7
2           3
3           5
4           4
5           4
6           1
7           6
8           1
9           7
10          2
```

So basically in 10 day the product 1 was the best selling item in 7 stores.
So the top 5 best selling item after 10 day looks like this :

```
Item    count of item
1           7
9           7
7           6
3           5
4           4
```

What I need is that this top 5 to be the first line in a new dataset called d1. The second line in d1 should be the top 5 in day 11, and so on.

```
#d1
Day   1st  2nd  3rd  4th  5th
01.10  1    9   7    3     4
01.11  9    1   7    3     4
```

Thank you!

Comment: do `data.frame(sort(table(unlist(your_dataframe)), decreasing = TRUE))`

Comment: What do you mean by being the first line?

Answer (score 0):

This is a better way to provide the data. Use `dput()` to get it into this form.

```
Days <- structure(list(Day = c(1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04, 1.05, 1.06, 1.07, 
     1.08, 1.09, 1.1), A = c(6L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 5L),
     B = c(3L, 7L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 7L), C = c(4L, 
     3L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 3L), D = c(9L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 
     5L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

To get the tabulation for 10 days, just collapse the data with `unlist()`:

```
FreqTable <- table(unlist(Days[, -1]))   # Tabulate all rows
FreqTable
# 
#  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
#  7  3  5  4  4  1  6  1  7  2 
Top5.freq <- sort(FreqTable, decreasing=TRUE)[1:5]   # Top 5 products
Top5.prod <- as.numeric(names(Top5.freq))                 # Product names
d1 <- data.frame(Day="1.10", t(Top5.prod))           # Row 1 of d1
colnames(d1)[-1] <- c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th")
d1
#    Day 1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th
# 1 1.10   1   9   7   3   4
```

You did not provide data for Day 11 or indicate if it represents a single day or a cumulation of days 1 - 11.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to combine Row1 , Row2 .... Row 10.